# Copy landscape orientation images from a folder to another in Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'd like to copy only landscape orientation images from a folder to another in Windows 7. I am looking for a scripted way to do this as I have a lot of folders with hundreds of images. I am new at batch, in fact this project is the reason why I am new at it.

Comment: `powershell "add-type -A System.Drawing; gci -r -i *.png,*.jpg | %{ $i=new-object drawing.bitmap $_.FullName; if ($i.Width -gt $i.Height -and !$i.Dispose()) { cp $_ 'c:\path\to\destination' } }"` will recursively copy all PNG and JPG files whose width is greater than its height.  If you want to learn batch or powershell scripting, you should make your questions more specific in the future.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  Also, MS-DOS isn't really a thing any more, unless you're actually writing this for Windows 3.1.  The "batch-file" tag is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you that worked, my apologies for the question.